# Как вывести переменную JS в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

В `HTML` есть код:

```
<script>
    var min = 0;
    document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = min;
</script>
```

И

```
  <body>                
        <h1 id="time">Итог - <div id="min"></div> </h1>                         
  </body>
```

Но вывод не получается.

Comment: Возможно не правильно подключаете `<script>`. Все выводиться. Попробуйте ваш `<script></script>` переместить под закрывающийся тег `</body>`

Comment: Да, в этом была причина. Спасибо!

Comment: переместить под закрывающийся тег `</body>` а не в `body` до `div`

Comment: Да, я понял. Спасибо. Только почему он выводит на следюущей строке?

Comment: Потому что `<div>` перепрыгивает на новую строку. Используйте вместо `<div>` -> `<span>`. Или для `<div>` примените стиль `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: @Puvvl под `<body>` что за бред вы пишите? Вы хоть где-то видели такое? Перед закрывающимся `<body>` может быть, а не после него.

Comment: Опечатка, сори, перед закрывающим тегом `</body>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все работает:

```js
    var min = 0;
    document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = min;
```

```html
<h1 id="time">Итог - <div id="min"></div> </h1>
```

Да, тут ошибка была лишь в том, что не прописалось еще все. Вообще скрипты лучше стараться ставить все после загрузки DOM и стилей. Так во всех фреймворках требуют. Хотя есть и такие, которые вы вынуждены будете закинуть в `<head>`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, учту на будущее